# Modifying a verb with "most" or "best"

Tags: grammar

most + verb   (Is this ever ok?)

The student who most epitomizes ambition: John Doe.
The man who most epitomizes masculinity: my father.

Other examples include:
Sneakers most symbolize the casual trend.
What most represents beauty to you?
Who most represents the idea of the "ugly American"?

I understand "most" with a noun, adverb, and adjective. But I hear "most represents" and "most epitomizes," but how can I explain why it's correct if it is indeed correct?

Is there a rule that applies to modifying a verb in this way as there are so many instances?

Comment: We would typically use the word *best* in place of most. But, it's not incorrect.

Comment: You should just be careful to only use it for verbs where it makes sense to have a degree or level of the verb. "Most represents" is probably good, from one of your examples. But "most exists" would not be good, since "exist" is binary. You exist, or you don't, there is no most.

Comment: @puppetsock: Thank you so much. Very, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Google and you'll find a number of uses of most + verb.  If common usage determines correctness, it is correct.  Or at least widely acceptable, even in carefully and professionally edited publications, like the example of "most epitomizes" in Vanity Fair - https://www.vanityfair.com/style/2018/03/what-you-should-know-about-erdem-moralioglu.

Being old school, however, I agree with David, that "best" is preferable to "most."

Comment: +1 for agreeing with me. But, beware of justifying things with common usage on this site. Most voters will prefer a source of authority rather than an example of usage in something like this.